# Simulate gamepad with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, gamepad-api

I'd like to write some Puppeteer-based tests to test some logic that makes use of the [Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API), but I can't find any documentation on the [Puppeteer docs](https://pptr.dev/) that explain how to simulate a gamepad and how to send button presses to the browser.

What's the proper way to do it?

Comment: Based on a quick glance at the two docs, I think you may need to extend page object to have `gamepad.eventName`. Gamepad uses events, and it seems that puppeteer ties objects like keyboard and mouse directly to events by name. So, follow the same formula. I'm not sure of what the specifics of the solution entail beyond that though. But hopefully that sends you down the right path. You may also achieved the same effect by considering the gamepads axis input as mouse input and button input as keyboard input. But that'd require an adapter pattern.

Comment: Gamepad API doesn’t work with events actually, the only events available are to know when a gamepad is connected or disconnected

Comment: It does not seem to have any API for simulating Gamepad API. One thing you can do is to override the Gamepad API and create your own simulator based on your custom button patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really a "proper" way to do it.

What I've done is made a somewhat clean way you should be able to use. It essentially involves creating your own game controller management code to use in puppeteer, and injecting the controller state into a page using the puppeteer `evaluate` API call.

Essentially we hijack the global scope `navigator.getGamepads` function and inject our own implementation.

We start out by modelling a game controller in code. The most basic part of a controller is a button. So lets do that.

```
class Button {
  constructor() {
    this.value = 0.0
    this.pressed = false
  }
  press() {
    this.value = 1.0
    this.pressed = true
  }
  unpress() {
    this.value = 0.0
    this.pressed = false
  }
  toObject() {
    return {
      value: this.value,
      pressed: this.pressed,
    }
  }
}
```

Next, according to the [W3C Gamepad Specification](https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/) a gamepad has two analog sticks, so we'll model those.

```
class AnalogStick {
  constructor() {
    this.button = new Button()
    this.xAxis = 0.0
    this.yAxis = 0.0
  }

  setXAxis(value) {
    this.xAxis = value
  }

  setYAxis(value) {
    this.yAxis = value
  }
}
```

Finally, let's create a class to represent a game pad. This class will have a helper function that translates the controllers internal state to match the [W3C Gamepad Interface signature](https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/#gamepad-interface).

```
class GamePad {
  constructor(index = 0) {
    this.id = 'Standard Gamepad'
    this.displayId = null // this is used for VR
    this.connected = true
    this.index = index
    this.mapping = 'standard'

    this.dPad = {
      up: new Button(),
      right: new Button(),
      down: new Button(),
      left: new Button(),
    }

    this.select = new Button()
    this.home = new Button()
    this.start = new Button()

    this.actions = {
      top: new Button(),
      right: new Button(),
      bottom: new Button(),
      left: new Button(),
    }

    this.leftStick = new AnalogStick()
    this.rightStick = new AnalogStick()

    this.lButton = new Button()
    this.lTrigger = new Button()

    this.rButton = new Button()
    this.rTrigger = new Button()
  }

  getState() {
    return {
      axes: [
        this.leftStick.xAxis,
        this.leftStick.yAxis,
        this.rightStick.xAxis,
        this.rightStick.yAxis,
      ],
      buttons: [
        this.actions.bottom.toObject(),
        this.actions.right.toObject(),
        this.actions.left.toObject(),
        this.actions.top.toObject(),

        this.lButton.toObject(),
        this.rButton.toObject(),

        this.lTrigger.toObject(),
        this.rTrigger.toObject(),

        this.select.toObject(),
        this.start.toObject(),

        this.leftStick.button.toObject(),
        this.rightStick.button.toObject(),

        this.dPad.up.toObject(),
        this.dPad.down.toObject(),
        this.dPad.left.toObject(),
        this.dPad.right.toObject(),

        this.home.toObject(),
      ],
      connected: this.connected,
      displayId: this.displayId,
      id: this.id,
      index: this.index,
      mapping: this.mapping,
    }
  }
}
```

Now we have a convenient way of representing a gamecontroller and its state in code, we can hijack `navigator.getGamepads` and replace it with our own function that returns the state of our virtual controllers.

Now we'll define a couple of helper functions. One that sets the gamepads state that `navigator.getGamepads` will return.

```
const setGamepadsState = async (page, gamepads) => {
  const result = await page.evaluate((controllers) => {
    navigator.getGamepads = () => controllers
  }, gamepads)
  return result
}
```

Now that we've done that, we need a way to trigger the `gamepadconnected` event. We can do that using the puppeteer `page.emit` function call.

```
const connectGamepad = async (page, gamepad) => {
  const connectedEvent = {
    gamepad,
  }
  page.emit('gamepadconnected', connectedEvent)
}
```

We now have all the building blocks to simulate a controller using puppeteer! Example usage is below:

```
;(async () => {
  const controller1 = new GamePad(0)
  const controller2 = new GamePad(1)
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goTo('https://www.yourgamepadpage.com')

  // Set the current gamepad state for both controllers in the puppeteer page.
  // We need to call this each time we change a controllers state
  await setGamepadsState(page, [controller1.getState(), controller2.getState()])

  // fires a 'gamepadconnected' event in the page for controller1
  await connectGamepad(page, controller1.getState())
  // fires a 'gamepadconnected' event in the page for controller2
  await connectGamepad(page, controller2.getState())

  // toggles the state of the bottom action button to pressed on controller1, 'X' on a playstation pad or 'A' on an xbox pad
  controller1.actions.bottom.press()
  await setGamepadsState(page, [controller1.getState(), controller2.getState()]) // passes controller1's current state into puppeteer's 'page.evaluate'

  // do a check here in your puppeteer based test!
  console.log('this should be whatever test code you need!')

  controller1.actions.bottom.unpress() // untoggles the state of the bottom action button on controller1

  // now lets simulate an analog stick axis shift, e.g. left analog stick on the horizontal axis all the way to the left.
  controller1.leftStick.setXAxis(-1.0)
  await setGamepadsState(page, [controller1.getState(), controller2.getState()]) // and now we pass it to the page context!

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Hopefully this should point you in the right direction. If you have any questions feel free to follow up here :)